How can I make a large TypeScript library with Vite without having an entry file and maintaining a giant set of barrel files?
I have a large TypeScript project that we are trying to split up into multiple libraries for sharing with other teams. These TypScript files are generally unrelated to each other so having a single entry point file like index.js doesn't make much sense. For example, we have a bunch of React components that we want to put into a UI library. Adding all of these components to a single root index.js/ts file and maintaining this file as we add and remove components from the library seems like a completely unnecessary annoyance.
How can I use Vite to create a TypeScript library with potentially hundreds of exports without adding them all into barrel files?

Don't provide a barrel.

You can't? Just use rollup for libraries. Vite is for applications. "maintaining this file as we add and remove components from the library seems like a completely unnecessary annoyance" just use star imports/exports for your subfolders.

When library code becomes quite large, I recommend separating it into several full-fledged nodejs/npm packages (locally). Put them all in one folder, have that folder house the repo root, and use tools such as yarn or pnpm workspaces for additional organization.
